# Saving textbox value from dynamic chart object

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have been trying to save the value of a textbox that is attached to a dynamically created chart object but it doesn't work even if I use localStorage. [Mycode](https://jsfiddle.net/j_darmawan/hrma1g5n/2/)

Pardon the mess of a code but if you add a chart, it creates the textbox alongside it but it won't save whatever is in it.

```
function createChart(dynamicData = '',number ='',dynamicval= '') {
    $('#super').append('<div id="bton"><button type="button" class="design_button" id="chart_'+number+'">&#10006</button><input id="text'+number+'" type = "textbox"/><div id="settings'+number+'"></div></div>');
    var value = document.getElementById("text"+number).value;
      localStorage.setItem("input",value);
    if(dynamicData == ''){

      var storeData = {
        'csvURL' : urlInput.value,
        'firstRowAsNames' : false,
      };
      localStorage.setItem('chart_'+number, JSON.stringify(storeData));
    }else{
      var storeData = dynamicData;
      var value = dynamicval;
      numbercnt = localStorage.getItem('chart_total');
    }

    var chartData = {
      csvURL: ipaddress + storeData.csvURL + extension,
      firstRowAsNames: storeData.firstRowAsNames,
      complete: function(csv) {
        csv.series[0].data.forEach(function(point, i) {
          csv.series[0].data[i] = {
            x: point[0],
            y: point[1],
            customInfo: csv.series[1].data[i][1]
          }

        })
        csv.series.pop()
      }
    };


    Highcharts.chart('settings' + number,{
      chart: {
        type: 'line'
      },
      title: {
        text: storeData.csvURL + ' Slip'
      },
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
        second: '%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%H:%M',
        hour: '%H:%M',
        day: '%e. %b',
        week: '%e. %b',
        month: '%b \'%y',
        year: '%Y'
      },
      data: chartData,
      series: [{
        name: 'Slip'
      }],

      yAxis: {

        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          color: 'black',
          width: 2,
          zIndex: 1
        }]

      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          color: 'red',
          negativeColor: 'green'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>Last Updated: <b>{point.customInfo}</b>'


      }
    });





    numbercnt++;
    localStorage.setItem('chart_total', numbercnt);

  }
```

Above is when the chart is created, and below is when it loads

```
function loadDynamicData(){
    var length =  localStorage.getItem('chart_total');
    for(var i =1;i<=length ;i++){
      if(localStorage.getItem('chart_'+i)){
        var dynamicData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chart_'+i));
        console.log(dynamicData)
        createChart(dynamicData,i);
        var dynamicval =localStorage.getItem("input");
        console.log(dynamicval)
        //if(localStorage.getItem("input") === null){
        //  return "";
        //}
        //return localStorage.getItem("input");
      }
    }
  }
  loadDynamicData();
});
```

Comment: where are you setting the value of the textbox? when you create it, it has empty text and that's what you are reading and setting in localstorage which will be empty only. (line 1-3 in createChart method).

Comment: Yeah seems to be the problem, what I intended is for it to be set after creating the chart and to be editable and saved to localstorage after the edit.

Comment: You need to do that then in input change event handler.

Comment: I tried putting the event handler in the append but it doesn't refer to the function instead an error came up with no reference

Comment: Don't do that. In 2nd line you get the element and assign change handler there.